# Jquery plugin for Converting HTML to Markdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, markdown

Am using bootstrap markdown comment box for comment option. am providing an option to edit. while editing, the html content should be appended inside the markdown. but it results in displaying the html tags.

[image]

I want to convert the html tag to markdown format. Is there any simplest jquery plugin to convert the html element to markdown??

Thanks in advance.

Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is probably what you're looking for, it's simple and has some interesting options.

https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown

Note: I've never used it but I've seen it around a couple of times.

Comment: thanks a lot :) it is very simple to use as i wanted. :) :)